# CSS not rendering as expected

Tags: css, reactjs

I have the following style in `Calculator.css`

```
.front {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.calc-wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

And when I import it into my component `Calculator.jsx`:

```
  import "./css/Calculator.css";
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="front">
        <div className="calc-wrapper">
          <Input input={this.state.input} />
          <div className="row">
            <Button>4</Button>
            <Button>5</Button>
            <Button>6</Button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

It displays three buttons in a row, as expected:

[image]

Now I'm flipping this component into another, `Field.jsx`.

Field.css

```
.back {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.field-wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
}

.field-row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```

And using the same logic at `Field.jsx`

```
import "./css/Field.css";
...
render() {
    const { items } = this.props;
      return (
       <div className="back">
          <div className="field-wrapper">
            <Output output={this.props} />
            <div className="field-row">
              <Position>{items[0]}</Position>
              <Position>{items[1]}</Position>
              <Position>{items[2]}</Position>
            </div>
        </div>
      );
  }
```

I'm displaying items horizontally...

[image]

---

**Position.css**

```
.position-wrapper {
  height: 4em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  background-color: #e0e1e6;
  color: #888888;
  flex: 1;
  outline: 1px solid #888888;
}

.field {
  background-color: #fe9241;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

---

**Position.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import "./css/Position.css";


const isOperator = val => {
  return !isNaN(val) || val === "." || val === "=";
};

export const Position = props => (
  <div
    className={`position-wrapper ${
      isOperator(props.children) ? null : "field"
    }`}
    onClick={() => props.handleClick(props.children)}
  >
    {props.children}
  </div>
);
```

---

What am I missing?

Comment: can you reproduce it in a code sandbox?

Comment: I don't get your whole code, but from when i tried to replicate your 3rd example It worked correctly for me. https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-williams-ds1eh
You can check the sandbox

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the property: `flex-direction:row;` to the item

```css
.field-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}
```

or to the item

```css
    .back {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: center;
      text-align: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
    }
```